# Simple Image Gallery plugin not displaying the images

Tags: joomla-3.x, plugin

I am using Simple Image Gallery plugin to preview my images in articles. However , when I add my images in the folder set in the configuration only the `{gallery}` tag is displayed and not the actual image.

I have double checked my directory and also that the plugin is enabled but everything seems to be correct. Also I changed the cache folder's permission to 777. Is there anything other than those listed above that may cause this problem to occur ?

Comment: I would suggest contacting the developer of this extension

Comment: Does your your server has PHP's GD image library installed? Have you enabled debug mode?

Comment: The problem was the missing GD image library. Thank you @iamrobert :)

Comment: ok - I'll post as an answer

Answer (score 2):

Please ensure that:
1. your server has PHP's GD image library installed
2. you can also enable debug mode

Also check user manual:
http://www.joomlaworks.net/extensions/free/simple-image-gallery